# change html attributes or style using php

Tags: php, jquery, html

Firstly to acknowledge this is regarding HTML element inside PHP page. How to change HTML element attributes or style when there's some changes detected by PHP?

The things similar to `jQuery` where it based in `#selectorID` or `.selectorClass` . Just I'm out of ideas on how to make this work on PHP.

The example of HTML element I like to get affected is `<li style=""></li>`.

How is this possible to set changes by PHP rather than jQuery?

Comment: Might be worth checking out [Dom Document](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: @Darren thanks. I'll have a look first & will back here if got any outcome or not.

Comment: Look up PHP DOM Parsers. I like Symfony's one: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html - assuming you understand what you can and what you cannot do to DOM in PHP.

Comment: PHP and *rendered* HTML never meet each other. PHP lives in the server, HTML is rendered on the client. What you can do is *generate different HTMLs* in the PHP. But once the HTML has been generated, the moving Finger has writ, and PHP can do nothing. jQuery, on the other hand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Your best bet is just putting a script tag inside or outside your php page.

Like

```
...?>
<script></script>
<?php...
```

or

```
<?php
echo"<script></script>";
?>
```

JQuery is NOT the only way you can change styles or attributes, imo native javascript is hell of a lot easier

Comment: but the question is I'm not intend to create new element, it just change the attributes or styles of existing element.

Comment: You can modify attributes and styles using

.setAttribute()

or .style

Comment: You don't just create elements using javascript

Comment: what about by href? is it possible? I'm asking this as this may benefits for others in future.

Comment: Nope. If you want the script to become external just use the <script> src attribute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133781/discussion-between-wafie-ali-and-muzkie).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add an if statement. If condition met then echo your desired html or styles like below:

```
if(blahblahblah){
   echo '<style type="text/css">
        li {
            display: none;
        }
        </style>';
}
```